# Можно ли через java установить время и дату на пк

Tags: java, время, дата, calendar

В java есть отличный класс `Calendar`, однако можно ли каким то образом задать время и дату компьютеру?

То есть я нажимаю на кнопку в приложении и время самого компьютера меняется на заданное в программе?

Если такой способ есть, то какой метод за это отвечает?

Comment: Дата и время пк это системные ресурсы - если кто-то ответит - да можно, уйду в монастырь.

Comment: Всё, ответа достаточно. Значит нельзя...

Comment: @0xdb костылями можно, через JNI или запуском внешней программы.

Comment: @0xdb, идите покупать рясу... В Linux'e должна сработать команда: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date -s \"2 OCT 2006 18:00:00\"")`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, зачем уходить в такие дебри? Просто выполнить команду в командной строке. Главное - чтобы были права доступа.

Comment: @0xdb сам я последний раз jni использовал году эдак в 2003-м, не готов заявить себя экспертом. Да и автору вопроса не рекомендую его использовать. Но в порядке повышения общего уровня образованности дам [ссылку на другой ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17035731/1911548).

Comment: Не, найду отговорку и пойду церковный дворик подмету, не более. В первом чтении я понял - средствами java, т.е. без внешних процессов и натуралок.

Answer (score 2):

*Хитросплетения моего карьерного пути снова занесли меня в суровые объятия JNI. Не удержался от того, чтобы не накидать по случаю ответ к этому вопросу.*

Код, написанный на Java, выполняется под управление виртуальной машины и от "реальной машины" изолирован. Как для переносимости, так и для безопасности. Поэтому из java-кода нельзя делать системных вызовов. Но с помощью механизма [JNI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) можно вызывать функции бинарных библиотек, на которые не действуют ограничения виртуальной машины. Далее я опишу пошаговый процесс разработки такой  библиотеки и работы с ней.

Первым делом нам нужен сам java-код. Поместим его в **Main.java**:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public native boolean setSystemTime(Calendar calendar);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("main");
        Main main = new Main();

        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        // Убавляем текущее время календаря на один час
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - 1);
        // Вызываем нативную функцию и передаём ей объект календаря
        boolean r = main.setSystemTime(c);

        System.out.println(r ? "Системные дата и время установлены" :
            "Ошибка установки системных даты и времени");
    }
}
```

Как видно, в коде есть только две строки отличающиеся от того, с чем приходится сталкиваться ежедневно. Это объявление нативного метода

```
public native boolean setSystemTime(Calendar calendar);
```

и загрузка библиотеки

```
System.loadLibrary("main");
```

Компилируем его:

```
javac -encoding utf-8 Main.java
```

Теперь необходимо из полученного класса сгенерировать заголовочный файл для нашей будущей библиотеки. В этом нам поможет утилита `javah` входящая в состав JDK:

```
javah Main
```

В рабочем каталоге должен появиться файл Main.h со следующим содержимым:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Main */

#ifndef _Included_Main
#define _Included_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Main
 * Method:    setSystemTime
 * Signature: (Ljava/util/Calendar;)Z
 */
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Main_setSystemTime
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

В нём интересно только объявление функции, имеющее вид `Java_<имя класса>_<имя метода>`. Первый параметр функции `JNIEnv` - это указатель на таблицу функций механизма JNI, служащих для обеспечения взаимодействия между java- и c-кодом. Второй параметр имеет тип `jobject` и принимает экземпляр класса `Main`. Третий параметр - это экземпляр класса `Calendar`. Возвращает функция `jboolean` соответствующий типу `boolean` в java. `JNIEXPORT` и `JNICALL` - это зависимые от компилятора макро-определения для экспортирования функций, особого внимания они не заслуживают.

А теперь самая интересная часть - реализация этой функции. Опишем её в файле **Main.c**:

```
#include "Main.h"
#include <time.h>
// Наше расширение будет работать как в Windows так и в Unux-системах
#if defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WIN32)
  #include <windows.h>
#else
  #include <sys/time.h>
#endif

// Константы класса Calendar
#define CALENDAR_DAY 5
#define CALENDAR_MONTH 2
#define CALENDAR_YEAR 1
#define CALENDAR_HOUR 11
#define CALENDAR_MINUTE 12
#define CALENDAR_SECOND 13

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Main_setSystemTime(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject objCalendar) {
    // Получаем класс Calendar
    jclass calendarClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, objCalendar);
    // Получаем метод get() класса Calendar
    // принимающий int и возвращающий int
    jmethodID mGet = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, calendarClass, "get", "(I)I");

    // Используя полученный метод, получаем дату и время
    // установленные в календаре
    jint day = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objCalendar, mGet, CALENDAR_DAY);
    jint month = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objCalendar, mGet, CALENDAR_MONTH);
    jint year = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objCalendar, mGet, CALENDAR_YEAR);
    jint hour = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objCalendar, mGet, CALENDAR_HOUR);
    jint minute = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objCalendar, mGet, CALENDAR_MINUTE);
    jint second = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objCalendar, mGet, CALENDAR_SECOND);

  #if defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WIN32)
    // Если код компилировался для Windows, будем использовать WinAPI
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);

    st.wYear = year;
    st.wMonth = month + 1;
    st.wDay = day;
    st.wHour = hour;
    st.wMinute = minute;
    st.wSecond = second;

    return SetLocalTime(&st);
  #else
    // Иначе системные вызовы Posix
    struct tm dateTime;
    dateTime.tm_year = year - 1900;
    dateTime.tm_mon = month;
    dateTime.tm_mday = day;
    dateTime.tm_hour = hour;
    dateTime.tm_min = minute;
    dateTime.tm_sec = second;

    struct timeval st;
    st.tv_sec = mktime(&dateTime);
    st.tv_usec = 0;

    if (settimeofday(&st, NULL) == -1)
        return JNI_FALSE;
    return JNI_TRUE;
  #endif
}

void main() {}
```

Для компиляции в Debian я использовал [GCC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection):

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC \
-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include \
-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux \
-shared -o libmain.so Main.c
```

Расположение заголовочных файлов JNI можно определить вызовом команды `locate jni.h`.

В Windows я использовал [MinGW-w64](https://mingw-w64.org):

```
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias ^
-I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" ^
-I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" ^
-shared -o main.dll Main.c
```

В первом случае в рабочем каталоге должен появиться файл `libmain.so`, а во втором `main.dll`. После этого можно запускать java-программу. Так как для смены системного времени требуются права системного администратора, в Windows запускать программу надо в консоли запущенной от имени администратора

```
java Main
```

а в Linux'ах

```
sudo java Main
```

Вот и всё. Не уверен, что это тот ответ, которого вы ждали, но может быть, он кому-нибудь пригодится.

*А впрочем, кого я обманываю, я просто хотел отправить @0xdb в монастырь :)*

Comment: @0xdb неее, ради этой шутки весь ответ писался.