# Как сделать проверку на процессы Windows [JAVA]

Tags: java

Как сделать проверку на процессы Windows если процесс VM.exe найден тогда программа закрывается если не найден тогда продолжает выполнение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean vmRunning = ProcessHandle.allProcesses()
                                 .map(ProcessHandle::info)
                                 .map(ProcessHandle.Info::command)
                                 .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                                 .anyMatch(s -> s.contains("VM.exe"));
```

Comment: У меня Java 8 это только для Java 9

Comment: Тогда только костылями, типа запуска `tasklist` и парсинга его выхлопа или получением списка процессов с помощью WinAPI в нативном коде через JNI.

Comment: Можешь отправить пример кода с WinAPI ?

Comment: [Примеры получения списка процессов с помощью WinAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-processes). [Пример работы с JNI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678881/204271).