# Импорт Библиотеки Java и С++

Tags: java, c++, c++11, библиотеки

я абсолютно не понимаю как написать код на одном языке и внедрить его в другой. Допустим на с++ я напишу вывод на консоль привет мир. во что это оборачивать в `jar`или `Dll` для подключения к `Java` проекту? код в `нетбинсе пишу` и допустим каким то чудом я его подключу как его вызывать? просторы интернета мне ничего не дают кроме ссылок на вопросы без ответов. Помогите если не сложно чайнику.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/353294/

Comment: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp

Comment: первое помогло. добавьте в ответы я отмечу. спасибо.

Comment: добавьте лучше сами и примите свой ответ. Только не ссылкой, а развёрнутым ответом с указанием источника.

Comment: Три года назад в порядке шутки писал [ответ, содержащий пошаговую инструкцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678881/204271).